# Spyder / iPython inline plot figure size

Tags: python, numpy, ipython, spyder

When I have a figure plotted from a script, I am able to vary the figure size as desired:

```
plt.figure(1,figsize=(20,20),dpi=72)
plt.imshow(a)
plt.show()
```

but when I do this in the iPython console, I cant get the figure size to vary. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) By default the figures created in the Spyder IPython console are PNG files of fixed size.

If you want to zoom in/out or pan to left/right in a Matplotlib figure, you need to change your graphics backend from `Inline` (the default) to `Automatic`. You can do this by going to the menu

`Tools > Preferences > IPython console > Graphics > Graphics backend`

After doing this and restarting the kernel of the IPython console, or creating a new console, all Matplotlib figures will be created in a new window with controls for zooming and panning.

Finally, if you want to switch between `Inline` and `Automatic` while working in the console, you need to run these commands

- `%matplotlib inline` to select the `Inline` backend.
- `%matplotlib qt5` or `%matplotlib qt` (depending if you're using Qt4 or Qt5) to select `Automatic`.

Comment: I am wondering if there is still no option to change the figure size in inline mode. It would be handy to be able to do so.

Comment: @MohammadReza, that option has been present since several years ago. In `Preferences > IPython console > Graphics > Inline backend` you can adjust the width, height and dpi of inline figures.

Comment: Just to add here, I had to restart spyder for changes to take an effect. Thanks